# Prefered way to handle state in history - react hooks

Tags: react-router, browser-history, react-hooks

I have a react web page where I need to make back button working. The state of the app is to much to push history as get to url and use router . What is the prefered way to hande this scenario in react as I cannot find any info on react page ?

Comment: Code sample would help immensely : ) Make sure to include all the necessary details.

Comment: This is not a code related question but generall one. You can immagine it as one page with 1000 inputs and corresponding 1000 state variables that are printed on the screen below. I need to make back button to iterate throught all history values stored in there.

Comment: I'd love to help you with this Krzysztof, however I just can't put your scenario together in my head based on the description. What have you tried already? Why didn't it work? What type of application is in question? Which router are you using? The question is too broad. Consider narrowing it down and providing as much details as possible.